# How use cookie Windows Phone c#

Tags: c#, cookies, windows-phone-8

I have problem. 
I have code on the main page:

```
      private async Task<string> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "myurl.com/page1";
            Uri address = new Uri(url);
            var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                           {
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Login", username),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", password)
                           };
            CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                CookieContainer = cookieJar,
                UseCookies = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false
            };

            var client = new HttpClient(handler)
            {
                BaseAddress = address
            };

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            string UrlBase = "myurl.com/page1";
            Uri uri = new Uri(UrlBase);
            var responseCookies = cookieJar.GetCookies(uri);
            foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
            {
                string cookieName = cookie.Name;
                string cookieValue = cookie.Value; 
            }    
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return body;
        }
         catch (Exception e)
        {

            return e.ToString();

        }

    }
```

But in debug I cant see cookies. And his number is 0. 
And I don`t know, how can I get myurl.com/page2 on the Page2.xaml?
How to use and save cookies?

Answer (score 0):

How to get and set cookies for Windows Phone 8

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dd920298(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dd920298%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried this method, but i dont get cookies. And i can`t get html code of page.

Comment: I too tried but I didnt get cookies ,can you please provide any alternate solution